# How to hide data of database but display it as an interactive visualization?

Tags: php, mysql, d3.js, data-visualization

I am currently working on a blog post to visualize data in an interactive way and I was planning to use the `d3.js` library for this. The collection of data took me almost half a year, which is the main reason I actually was planning to keep it locked in a database and only retrieve the data for visualization purposes. This way I can offer data services.

However, because I am using the d3 library, all the data is accessible on the client site. There are options like aggregating the data, which I will certainly do, but it would still make it possible to combine the aggregated data and derive the whole database from it.

So my question now is: Is there any way of, for instance, only getting the visualization itself, without having the actual data on client site? It is important that visualization stays interactive (i.e. no pre-rendered images).

FYI: I have no admin access to my website's server and run Wordpress as my CMS. My database is MySQL and currently, I am deriving data from the database with PHP.

Comment: I suspect it depends on the kind of information being communicated. I can show you how this year's house prices and total sales compare with last year without ever revealing the price of a house or the quantity sold, but that's not to say you couldn't still extrapolate that data from other sources.

Comment: You could render the chart or whatever other visualization on the server on the fly. If you think you must render on the client side, there isn't any real way to do that without sending the data to the client. A lot will depend on what kind of data you are rendering, and how much data there is. For example, if you have a lot of data, you could limit the resolution of the rendering and send aggregated data rather than discrete data points. For smaller subsets, you could send discrete data points. Truth is, if someone wants the dataset, and you send discrete data points, they can get it.

Comment: ...and lots of pie charts

Comment: Not sure what you mean, because visualization *is* data, just not in a numeric format. If you only care about general shape, then you could probably map all your numbers  from [min, max] to [0, 1], and then perhaps fuzzy them with a random error of 1% or so

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, you can try using [MySQL views](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/view-syntax.html), to return only needed data, ie aggregations, and not raw data. Check [this tutorial](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-views-tutorial.aspx) to get familiar with views. However, this data can also be parsed, the only way to keep data secure is to not show it to the user.